# Error Installing Microsoft CNTK

Tags: cntk

During installation I received the following error:

> This script will setup the CNTK prequisites and the CNTK Python
>   environment onto the machine. More help is given by calling 'get-help
>   .\install.ps1' in your powershell environment.
>
> The script will analyse your machine and will determine which
>   components are required. The required components will be downloaded in
>   [C:\local\Scripts\windows\InstallCache] Repeated operation of this
>   script will reuse already downloaded components.
>
> - If required VS2012 Runtime and VS2013 Runtime will be installed
> - If required MSMPI will be installed
> - If required the standard Git tool will be installed
> - CNTK source will be cloned from Git into [c:\repos\CNTK]
> - Anaconda3 will be installed into [C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64]
> - A CNTK-PY34 environment will be created in [C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs]
> - CNTK will be installed into the CNTK-PY34 environment
>
> 1 - I agree and want to continue Q - Quit the installation process
>
> 1 Determining Operations to perform. This will take a moment...
>
> The following operations will be performed:  * Setup/Update CNTK Wheel
>   * Clone CNTK from Github repository
>
> Do you want to continue? (y/n) y Performing download operations
>   Download operations finished
>
> Performing install operations Setup/Update of CNTK Wheel environment.
>   Please be patient.... You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version
>   9.0.0 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command. Cloning CNTK (branch v2.0.beta2.0)
>   repository....
>
> Fatal error during script execution! 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: This command cannot be run due to
>   the error: The system cannot find the file specifie d.    at
>   System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord
>   errorRecord)
>
> PS C:\local\Scripts\windows>

I'm not familiar with powershell, so I am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of questions. Are you using *beta1* or *beta2*?
If you are using *beta1*, just a reminder that there is a *beta2* now available with bug fixes and also some improvements to the install script, but I don't think this particular problem has been addressed!

It looks like the clone of the *cntk git* repository is failing.

Was *Git* installed on your machine? Is there a GIT.EXE in `c:\Program Files\Git\bin\?`

I think the install found an existing `git.exe` (in a different location), and is now trying to call it at the 'wrong' location.

The easiest workaround for you (if you have git installed), from a command prompt:

```
 cd c:/
 md \repos
 cd repos
 clone --branch v2.0.beta1.0 --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK
```

If you have moved to *beta2*, replace the *v2.0.beta1.0* with *v2.0.beta2.0*